# Proving that sequences with the pattern aaaaaaa don't include a perfect square

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

I need help with the following problem:

> Which of the following sequences doesn't have perfect square:
>
> A) $11, 111, 1111, \dots$
>
> B) $33, 333, 3333, \dots$
>
> C) $44, 444, 4444, \dots$
>
> D) $77, 777, 7777, \dots$

I proved that the first sequence cannot contain a perfect square, but it seems that none of them contains a perfect square. Is it possible to  write a proof for a general pattern $aaaaaaaaa$?

Comment: How can perfect squares end?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No square ends in $3$ or in $7$.

No square ends in $11$.

But some squares end in $44$, but never mind if $44\cdots 44$ is a square,
so is $11\cdots11$ which isn't.

Comment: Please clarify the last sentence.

Comment: @immibis If 44...4 was a perfect square, so would be 11...1, but we know the latter isn't a square.

Comment: Why does $44\cdots 44$ being square imply $11\cdots 11$ is square? Is it because we can divide out 4 (which is itself square)?

Comment: @BrianJ that's right!

Answer (score 5):

For 1 you are done.
For 2 not divisible by 4.
For 3 no perfect square ends with digit 3.
For 4 just divide by 4 and get back to the case with 1.
For 5 not divisible by 25.
For 6 not divisible by 4.
For 7 no perfect square ends in digit 7.
For 8 not divisible by 16.
For 9 divide by 9 and get back to 1.

Comment: Also, please explain why for 1 we are done.

Comment: because he has already proved it.

Comment: Soumik Gosh: Please write complete sentences so that everyone can understand.

Comment: @MattiP The question states "I proved that the first sequence cannot contain a perfect square"

Comment: For 1 (we do modulo 4 checking) , see that except 1 , no other term in the sequence 1,11,111,1111,...... is of the form $4k+1$ or $4k$. Done !!